# Каким образом запретить отправку формы пустых строк в базу данных?

Tags: php, mysqli

1. Есть некая форма, которая по умолчанию шлет пустые строки в php файл

   ```
   <form>
     <input type="name" class="form-control" id="example" placeholder="Ваше имя">
   </form>
   ```
2. Собственно в php файле, проверяю на наличие тегов

   ```
   $name = strip_tags($mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
   ```
3. Далее при отправке данных на сервер, появляется пустая строка, и при обратном выводе также.

Каким образом поставить запрет на NULL через php?

Comment: а просто наличие данных вы проверить не можете, что `$_POST['name']`  не пусто?

Comment: пробовал epmty(), и пробовал null !==, который впоследствии начал выводить лишь цифру 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (trim($_POST['name']) === '')
  die('Name is empty')
```

Answer (score -1):

для начала навешай атрибут name на поля, типа

```
<form>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="example" placeholder="Ваше имя">
    </form>
```

Ты еще в html мож навешать `required` на нужные поля, типа

```
<form>
  <input type="text"  name="name" class="form-control" id="example" required placeholder="Ваше имя">
</form>
```

тогда форма не будет отправляться, пока пользователь не заполнит все поля с `required`

или в PHP есть ф-ция `empty()`

```
if(!empty(trim($_REQUEST('name')))) {//вместо $_REQUEST можно $_POST или $_GET в зависимости от типа запроса
//здесь действия записи в БД
}
```

P.S.: типа поля name (type="name") не существует

Comment: empty() в вашем коде - это бессмыслица